# DatePicker Fragment leaks when I turn the screen

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, datepickerdialog, datapicker

I'm using the DatePickerFragment class to set data to a textView.
The class is working, but when I turn the screen the aplication crashes.

The code of DataPicker class:

```
class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    public TextView textview_editTextVnosDatuma;
    public DatePickerFragment(TextView elementVKateregaSeShraniDatum){
        textview_editTextVnosDatuma = elementVKateregaSeShraniDatum;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar C = Calendar.getInstance();
        int y = C.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int m = C.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int d = C.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, y, m, d);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        textview_editTextVnosDatuma.setText(""+year+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+day);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the class from a method(in an Activity) that starts with a click on a textview:

```
public void SetTheData(View view){
    new DatePickerFragment(((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextInsertData))).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

And this is the error in LogCat:

```
07-09 10:52:32.140: W/dalvikvm(5748): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bfb1f8)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.miniMAX.mmcitalnik/com.miniMAX.mmcitalnik.VnosPrejemaIzdaje}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.miniMAX.mmcitalnik.DatePickerFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:128)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1165)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.miniMAX.mmcitalnik.DatePickerFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:405)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1767)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:208)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at com.miniMAX.mmcitalnik.VnosPrejemaIzdaje.onCreate(VnosPrejemaIzdaje.java:57)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     ... 12 more
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.miniMAX.mmcitalnik.DatePickerFragment; no empty constructor
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
07-09 10:52:32.171: E/AndroidRuntime(5748):     ... 19 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In the Manifest file, make sure you added all your Activities and that you add handle orientation for each Activity

Comment: I added all my Activities to the manifest...

Answer (score 1):

Make your `DatePickerFragment` class public, and provide an empty, public constructor.

Comment: yes that work, but now when i turn the screen and try to save, the app crash, becouse I don't know how to pass the textview to the DatePickerFragment class :/

Comment: I don't think you should be passing views between fragments... Perhaps you should think of another way for communication between the fragment and the activity's `TextView`?